# Error while connecting to Mobile First server on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-cli, mobilefirst-appcenter, mobilefirst-bluemix

Getting error when I try to connect to Mobile First server instance in Bluemix.
Please find the attached screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Did you make any changes in server settings ?

Comment: The error you saw is usually because of  a non-existing end point. Doublecheck if the server URL that you provided to the `mfpdev` CLI is correct. 
To get the URL: On the IBM Cloud console, navigate to the Mobile Foundation service -> Service credentials and check for `url` in the credentials JSON.

Comment: I have not made any changes in the server settings.{
  "user": "admin",
  "password": ***********
  "url": "https://mobilefoundation-90ba-server.mybluemix.net"
}

Comment: Did you possibly try adding the server too soon? ie, immediately after you created it? What if you try later? Does it work? The other test is try with the "http" and port 80 and see if the behaviour is any different

Comment: I tried after 2 hours, tried with http an port 80 but the result is same, same error.